# recursiveDescription not printing full hierarchy and includes escaped line breaking

Tags: ios, debugging

In Xcode 6.3.1 when using recursive description I often get output that looks like:

```
(lldb) p [thisUIView recursiveDescription]
(__NSCFString *) $16 = 0x132f4b90 @"<UIVIew: 0x1eb14d30; frame = (0 0; 768 314); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <Layer: 0x1e850160>>\n   | <UIVIew: 0x134ae410; frame = (724 0; 44 82); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x134a8560>; layer = <Layer: 0x134b2080>>\n   |    | <UIVIew: 0x134f5690; frame = (0 0; 44 82); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <Layer: 0x1ea360c0>>\n   | <UIVIew: 0x1ea3d160; frame = (724 82; 44 58); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x134f71d0>; layer = <Layer: 0x1349b1d0>>\n   |    | <UIVIew: 0x1ea3d520; frame = (0 0; 44 58); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <Layer: 0x134a7a40>>\n   | <UIVIew: 0x132dc560; frame = (724 140; 44 29); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x132f6b30>; layer = <Layer: 0x132dc600>>\n   |    | <UIVIew: 0x132eee40; frame = (0 0; 44 29); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <Layer: 0x132dc660>>\n   | <UIVIew: 0x1349cae0; frame = (724 169; 4"
```

Notice how the returned string contains escaped line breaking, "\n", and how the string abruptly stops? The object thisUIView has 8 children, only four of which are being printed.

What's happening here? Is this a bug in recursiveDescription? Could it be the result of something I've done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When lldb prints strings of any sort, it prints them raw.  In general, when you are debugging you want to see the actual contents of the string, with literal "\n" etc.

Also, lldb truncates string printing at the value of the setting: target.max-string-summary-length, which is 1024 by default.  That is mostly to keep it from going crazy when it comes across an unterminated string.

To view longer strings, do:

```
(lldb) settings set target.max-string-summary-length <SomeLargeNumber>
```

Note, `print` is intended to give you the "rawer" view of the NSString (rawer because the NSString itself is a complex beast, and may not hold its contents in some nice single bugger...).

However, `po` - i.e. print-object - is intended to give you a prettied up display.  So in your case if you use `po` rather than `p` to print the object, it won't be truncated, and we'll print it to the console with all the \n's rendered as newlines, etc...

Comment: hahahaha... so basically... I was being pretty stupid. Sigh. Well thanks for taking the time to answer me anyway!